# GetStream.io API key rotation

Tags: getstream-io

Is there a way to change/rotate the API key for a GetStream.io app? If so, can there be multiple API keys active in parallel, or will all clients need to immediately get a new JWT upon key rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetStream developer here.

You can actually issue new keys using our Dashboard. In API Keys section there's `Add New` button that you can use to create a new key. All keys will be active so you can transition your clients to the new key and then delete the old one when you feel safe doing so.

I'm not sure why you've got such response from our support, something for us to improve on.

[image: Dashboard Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

I reached out to GetStream support, and was told:

> Thanks for getting in touch. Sorry, this is not possible. The only way to change your API credentials would be to create and use a new application from the dashboard.

Unfortunately, creating the new application will not contain any of the data from the existing application other than settings.